# Vinyl flooring adhesive problems

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I've recently laid some vinyl flooring, it's the peel and stick vinyl flooring squares and I used Henry VCT 257 adhesive I don't think I let the adhesive get tacky enough, the tile is laid on top of some old linoleum, I used floor leveler to level it out and fill cracks the best I could and there is adequate air circulation and Heat in the room my question is will the wet adhesive Ever Dry or will I need to pull up the pieces that aren't sealing and scrape off some of the adhesive and let it get more tacky?

Comment: Peel and stick comes with the adhesive it needs. If you're not using VCT (which has no adhesive on it), you don't need VCT adhesive, and it's not even "a good idea"...

Comment: I've used peel and stick flooring before and if I put it in a high traffic area it always came up sometime, with this current project parts of the floor I've scraped it down almost completely and set the tiles back in place and they've dried fine, I guess I'll have to do that with the rest of the flooring, thank you for commenting

Comment: Hi Wes, the point is that you are mixing too different adhesives that may have interacted with each other.  The result is going to be unpredictable.

Comment: I got you, I think what I'll probably do is just scrape as much as I can off and reset the tile that seemed to work on other pieces